# Bash script segfaults on brk()

Tags: c, linux, bash, malloc, brk

can someone explain why this "endless" loop segfaults quickly? 
For example, let's say we have this function:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
  foo 
}; foo
```

This segfaults after **8-10** seconds. Examining via strace, we can see a lot of **brk()** calls:

```
brk(0x2e11000)                          = 0x2e11000
brk(0x2e12000)                          = 0x2e12000
brk(0x2e13000)                          = 0x2e13000
brk(0x2e14000)                          = 0x2e14000
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x7ffcddf5ff68} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

My questions are:

1. is this segfaulting because it's trying to access an unmapped region in memory space (via brk)?
2. If yes, why is it trying to access it?
3. Would malloc() be a better choice here?
4. If you have any extra/trivia information on this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it is more related to stack corruption out of recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `brk`s are not related. It segfaults because it runs out of stack space. If you reduce the available stack with `ulimit -s 512; ./yourscript` you'll see that it crashes much quicker.
2. It gobbles up all stack space because you have an infinitely recursive function and bash does not do tail call optimization.
3. It already uses `malloc` (or a bash specific version thereof). Since `malloc` is a C library function and not a syscall, it does not show up in `strace`. There is no problem with allocated memory though, it's running out of stack space.
4. The `brk`s are used to store some of the infinite metadata associated with your infinite recursion, but it's not enough to matter.

   Crashes in infinitely recursive functions happens in various forms in all languages when you have unbounded recursion that isn't optimized. Try `void foo() { foo(); }` in Java, or `def foo(): foo()` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're seeing is a the stack growing until resources are depleted. In short, it's a recursion issue.

Take a look at the [brk()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) call, and you'll see it's changing the end of the process's data segment. Increasing the program break is allocating memory to the process, but you don't have an inexhaustible supply. When you run out, it crashes.

But as to your third question, even the notes section in the documentation suggests that malloc() is the better choice.